# PDA Anchor Test: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client, testing

I was playing around with PDA's in anchor, but I'm having problems writing tests for it.

When I try to use anchor's worspace to create a transaction I get the error:

```
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account
```

What's interesting is that if I deploy the app and write a frontend to talk with it with very similar code, everything works, it's only when I try to test it that I have problems.

Here's the simple SC I wrote:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use std::mem::size_of;

declare_id!("3Z3dWerEbF5RGtcu7S3avuKRMSnHr8tUoJ69AhEWSDHM");

#[program]
pub mod demo_pda {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_escrow(ctx: Context<CreateEscrow>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        // Get Escrow Account
        let escrow = &mut ctx.accounts.escrow;

        // Set from
        escrow.from = ctx.accounts.from.key();
        // Set to
        escrow.to = ctx.accounts.to.key();
        // set amount
        escrow.amount = amount;

        Ok(())
    }
}

/// CreateEscrow context
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateEscrow<'info> {
    // Escrow Account PDA
    #[account(
        init,
        // State account seed uses the string "state" and the users' key. 
        // Note that we can only have 1 active transaction
        seeds = [b"escrow".as_ref(), from.key().as_ref(), to.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = from,
        space = size_of::<EscrowAccount>() + 16
    )]
    pub escrow: Account<'info, EscrowAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: safe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// Escrow Account Structure
#[account]
pub struct EscrowAccount {
    // From address
    pub from: Pubkey,

    // To address
    pub to: Pubkey,

    // Amount that is owed
    pub amount: u64,
}
```

And here's the test I wrote for it:

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { utf8 } from "@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/utils/bytes";
import { BN } from "bn.js";
import { assert } from "chai";
import { DemoPda } from "../target/types/demo_pda";

describe("demo-pda", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.DemoPda as Program<DemoPda>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const toWallet: anchor.web3.Keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const [escrowPDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [utf8.encode('escrow')],
      program.programId
    );
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.local();
    const tx = await program.methods.createEscrow(new BN(32)).accounts({
      from: provider.wallet.publicKey,
      to: toWallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram:  anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      escrow: escrowPDA
    }).rpc();
  });
});
```

Does anyone know why I'm only getting errors when trying to send a transaction with PDA's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JS test code, replace this

```
    const [escrowPDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [utf8.encode('escrow')],
      program.programId
    );
```

with this

```
    const [escrowPDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
        utf8.encode('escrow'),
        provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        toWallet.publicKey.toBuffer()
      ],
      program.programId
    );
```

The parameters you pass into `findProgramAddress` must match the seeds you specified in the Rust/Anchor code, in this case `eeds = [b"escrow".as_ref(), from.key().as_ref(), to.key().as_ref()]`.

Comment: Omg.... I swore I did that, but I guess not! That explains why my sample front end code works, but not my tests... Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The client side findProgranAddress line uses different seeds than the anchor program:

```
seeds = [b"escrow".as_ref(), from.key().as_ref(), to.key().as_ref()],
```

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right, I forgot to include the correct seed.